# How to prove that canonical projection is quotient map.?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space.
Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $X$.
Let $p: X\to X{/}{\sim}$ be the canonical projection.

I don’t know how to prove that canonical projection is a quotient map?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the quotient topology?

Comment: What is your definition of the topology on $X{/}{\sim}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the topology on $X{/}{\sim}$ is defined to be the quotient topology, i.e. $O \subset X{/}{\sim}$ is open iff $p^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$.

By definition, then, $p$ is a quotient map.